# Variable user input not stored?

Tags: python, function, web-scraping, input, beautifulsoup

```
def url_input():
    my_url = input('Enter your url: ')

def sheet_function():
    '''Default - Find brands, product titles, and sRGB info from page'''

    # Open urlopen function in request module in urllib library
    from urllib.request import urlopen as user_request
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup

    url_input()
    # Change the url to the products page you want to analyze, needs to be Newegg
    # my_url = 'https://www.newegg.com/p/pl?N=100160979%20601305587%20600556721'

    # open up connection and grab html content from url#
    user_client = user_request(my_url)

    # load content onto variable
    page_html = user_client.read()

    # close the client
    user_client.close()

    page_soup = soup(page_html, "html.parser")

    filename = "monitors.csv"
    f = open(filename, "w")

    headers = "Brand, Product_Name, High_sRGB\n"

    f.write(headers)

    # find all brands
    for container in page_soup.select('.item-container'):
        brand = container.select_one('.item-branding img')
        brand = brand['title'] if brand else '- No Brand -'

        title = container.select_one('.item-title').get_text(strip=True)

    #   print('Brand: {}'.format(brand))
    #   print('Product_name: {}'.format(title))
    #   print('-' * 160)

    # Can change sRGB to other detail such as HDR10, USB-C, etc.
    # would need to change parameters below and headers
        if "sRGB" in title:
            High_sRGB = "Yes"
    #        print("THIS PRODUCT HAS A GOOD SRGB RATING")
    #        print('-' * 160)
        else:
            High_sRGB = "No"
    #       print("No SRGB rating.")
    #       print('-' * 160)

        f.write(brand + "," + title.replace(",","|") + "," + High_sRGB + "\n")

    f.close()

sheet_function()
```

I'm able to get this information into a csv file, but now I want to create a function that allows the user to input their own Newegg url instead of defining the my_url as seen commented out. I'm not sure if it's an issue with variable type or if the input just isn't being registered.

I'm new to this so sorry if my mistake is obvious. This is the error I receive.

```
Enter your url: https://www.newegg.com/p/pl?N=100160979%20601305587%20600556721
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "chanl.py", line 59, in <module>
    sheet_function()

  File "chanl.py", line 16, in sheet_function
    user_client = user_request(my_url)
  NameError: name 'my_url' is not defined
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make the first function return the url, otherwise, you need to make `my_url` global, which is considered a bad practice. Try this:

```
def url_input():
    my_url = input('Enter your url: ')
    return my_url # return the string

def sheet_function():
    '''Default - Find brands, product titles, and sRGB info from page'''

    # Open urlopen function in request module in urllib library
    from urllib.request import urlopen as user_request
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup

    my_url = url_input() # Store the returned string into a variable
    # Change the url to the products page you want to analyze, needs to be Newegg
    # my_url = 'https://www.newegg.com/p/pl?N=100160979%20601305587%20600556721'

    # open up connection and grab html content from url#
    user_client = user_request(my_url)

    # load content onto variable
    page_html = user_client.read()

    # close the client
    user_client.close()

    page_soup = soup(page_html, "html.parser")

    filename = "monitors.csv"
    f = open(filename, "w")

    headers = "Brand, Product_Name, High_sRGB\n"

    f.write(headers)

    # find all brands
    for container in page_soup.select('.item-container'):
        brand = container.select_one('.item-branding img')
        brand = brand['title'] if brand else '- No Brand -'

        title = container.select_one('.item-title').get_text(strip=True)

    #   print('Brand: {}'.format(brand))
    #   print('Product_name: {}'.format(title))
    #   print('-' * 160)

    # Can change sRGB to other detail such as HDR10, USB-C, etc.
    # would need to change parameters below and headers
        if "sRGB" in title:
            High_sRGB = "Yes"
    #        print("THIS PRODUCT HAS A GOOD SRGB RATING")
    #        print('-' * 160)
        else:
            High_sRGB = "No"
    #       print("No SRGB rating.")
    #       print('-' * 160)

        f.write(brand + "," + title.replace(",","|") + "," + High_sRGB + "\n")

    f.close()

sheet_function()
```

Answer (score 2):

This has to do with scope in python. The variable `my_url` in `url_input()` can only be accessed inside of `url_input()`

One way to fix this is by returning `my_url` and then assigning it to a variable in `sheet_function()` like so:

```py
def url_input():
    my_url = input('Enter your url: ')
    return my_url  # RETURNED VALUE

def sheet_function():
    '''Default - Find brands, product titles, and sRGB info from page'''

    # Open urlopen function in request module in urllib library
    from urllib.request import urlopen as user_request
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup

    my_url = url_input()  # ASSIGNED TO VARIABLE
    # Change the url to the products page you want to analyze, needs to be Newegg
    # my_url = 'https://www.newegg.com/p/pl?N=100160979%20601305587%20600556721'

    # open up connection and grab html content from url#
    user_client = user_request(my_url)

    # load content onto variable
    page_html = user_client.read()

    # close the client
    user_client.close()

    page_soup = soup(page_html, "html.parser")

    filename = "monitors.csv"
    f = open(filename, "w")

    headers = "Brand, Product_Name, High_sRGB\n"

    f.write(headers)

    # find all brands
    for container in page_soup.select('.item-container'):
        brand = container.select_one('.item-branding img')
        brand = brand['title'] if brand else '- No Brand -'

        title = container.select_one('.item-title').get_text(strip=True)

    #   print('Brand: {}'.format(brand))
    #   print('Product_name: {}'.format(title))
    #   print('-' * 160)

    # Can change sRGB to other detail such as HDR10, USB-C, etc.
    # would need to change parameters below and headers
        if "sRGB" in title:
            High_sRGB = "Yes"
    #        print("THIS PRODUCT HAS A GOOD SRGB RATING")
    #        print('-' * 160)
        else:
            High_sRGB = "No"
    #       print("No SRGB rating.")
    #       print('-' * 160)

        f.write(brand + "," + title.replace(",","|") + "," + High_sRGB + "\n")

    f.close()

sheet_function()
```

Where I made capital comments are where I added a line of code. This should allow access to the variable `my_url` inside of `sheet_function()`. You could change `my_url` in `sheet_function()` to any name you want, as long as thats how you refer to it in that function.